# Unable to find lmdb while installing caffe with make all

Tags: caffe, lmdb

[/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lmdb
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:568: recipe for target '.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3' failed
make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0-rc3] Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9iAd.png)

How to get rid of this problem.

Comment: Make sure that the library file your trying to use while compiling is present in the path that your using while compiling... give the command that you are using for compiling.

Comment: Thank you Dheeraj.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the library file your are trying to use while compiling is present in the path that your have given while compiling...